# Java HashMap and public static void main(String args[])

Tags: java, hashmap

i'm working on a project that i have to use HashMaps on.

I'm fairly new to java, so am i right in thinking that you have to include this in each class that I want to use HashMaps on, or should this be included in each class anyway?

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

This is the whole class. Ive tried it without the main method but I just get errors.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Product
{
     public static void main(String args[]) {

     HashMap<String, int> product = new HashMap<String, int>();

     product.put("product1", 1);
     product.put("product2", 2);
   }

}
```

If i dont have the main method in it comes up with an error on the line...

```
product.put("prodcut1", 1);
```

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: No, why would you need a main method everywhere?

Comment: HashMaps don't seem to work when they are not in the main method? @LouisWasserman

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug completely unrelated to that.  Please provide the code that "doesn't seem to work," and explain what "doesn't seem to work" actually means here.

Comment: I've changed the question @LouisWasserman

Comment: _If i dont have the main method in it comes up with an error on the line..._ is not a helpful statement. What does _don't have_ mean? Did you just remove the `main` method declaration? Did you remove the brackets? Are the other statements just floating in the class body or did you put them in another method? What error are you getting? Do you know what a `main` method is meant to do?

Comment: It is such a pity that the exact error message is a secret. Otherwise, we might be able to help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that your code has to be in the main method, but it has to be in *some* method, or an initializer block.  If you put your code in a non-main method, it will still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You only need main in the driver of your program not in every single class. After having written your code/classes that require HashMaps you can then put them inside

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Also since you mentioned HashMaps are not working, have you imported them in the other classes where you are trying to use them like so?

```
import java.util.HashMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.  A `main` method serves as the main starting point for an entire program.  It has no bearing on what classes can be used in the program.

If you want to use a HashMap...

1. Include the package that houses the HashMap class
2. Declare variables of the type HashMap

   - Either as instance fields of a class or as local variables in a method/function
3. Use the variables you declared

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to declare the HashMap at the time of declaration and you dont want the initialization to be in a method or block, you can use the following:

```
HashMap<String, int> product = new HashMap<String, int>(){{
    put("product1", 1);
    put("product2", 2);
}};
```